# Возможно ли создать таблицу в MySQL, чтобы она жила 6 месяцев, а позже в бекап и удалить

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Интересует автоматизированное удаление/+добавка в бекап таблицы после определенного срока времени.
Такое возможно осуществить?
Что для этого нужно знать от языка `php`, или `MySQL`? или?

Comment: Вышестоящий комментарий можно преобразовать в ответ.. Вроде добавить больше нечего..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Или использовать [Cron](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). К примеру, [эта статья поможет](http://masterhost.ru/support/doc/cron/) войти в курс дела.